# x509 authentication is skipped on Spring Boot Flux application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to establish x509 authentication for Spring Boot Flux application, and I'm getting such message during authentication attempt:

> org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerX509AuthenticationConverter : No peer certificates found in SslInfo, skipping x509 authentication

When I'm trying to debug class that is mentioned in this log message, I can see that certificates info is indeed null in there.

My current configuration:

Ssl certificates are provided though Spring Boot properties (like *server.ssl.key-store*), Ssl connection is successful. For testing purposes, I copied certificates from another Spring Boot application (not Flux one though) with working x509 authentication.

I need to run multiple applications locally, so I distinguish them by port. For this one, port configuration is

> server.port=${port:8441}

For spring security, I have specific configuration class, marked with @Configuration and @EnableWebFluxSecurity annotations. Inside that class, I'm defining a bean in such a way:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain (ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    String endpoint1 = "/first-endpoint-i-want-to-authorize";
    String endpoint2 = "/second-endpoint-i-want-to-authorize";
    
    http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.matchers(
        new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                Arrays.asList(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher(endpoint1, null),
                new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher(endpoint2, null)
            )
        )
        )
    ).permitAll());
    
    http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.pathMatchers(endpoint1, endpoint2).authenticated())
    .x509(x509 -> x509.principalExtractor(authenticationService).authenticationManager(authenticationService))
    .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
    .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance());

    return http.build();
}
```

Credentials authentication seems to work with this configuration. Also, **authenticationService** is an autowired bean that implements all required interfaces, but it implementation seems unconnected with root cause of the situation because of the fact none of implemented methods are called during authentication attempt.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid empty certificates, client authorization should be set to "need" mode. If configuring through **.properties** file, it can be done like this:

> server.ssl.client-auth=need